# Image processing to detect water diseases

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Is there any way to detect water diseases using image processing ? and is there any way to develop it in android or in matlab thank you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can.
You create a system able to collect samples from water periodically.
Them take a picture from sample using a microscopy.
And finally look for any protozoo.

Amebiase, look for this man : [here](http://www.cdc.gov/parasites/amebiasis/)
Giardia, look for this: [here](http://www.cdc.gov/parasites/giardia/index.html)

Is hard but always possible.